# How do I open and convert old Microsoft-generated videos "AVSEQ01.DAT"?

Tags: file-conversion

Digital-AV savants? I’ve inherited a dozen 20-year-old family video files saved in a format that refuses to be converted, copied, opened, read, renamed, or moved from the CDs on which they were originally stored. Troubleshooting and tapping into almost a dozen converter programs has left me nowhere and close to tossing the disks untapped. I’d much prefer to save the files for posterity in a viewable format. Any tips?

Here’s the summary:

- 20-year-old Memorex CDs, operated perfectly on a Windows system back in the day and stored in a cool, dark, basement in their cases until now. The CDs open perfectly to show folders (EXT, MPEGAV, SEGMENT, and VCD).
- Each video appears in the MPEGAV folder as “AVSEQ01.DAT” and averages about 125MB in size.
- I’m operating on an iMac11,3 running 10.13.6, but I have easy access to Windows.
- Attempts to copy the file to a Mac desktop gets the error: “Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in AVSEQ01.DAT can’t be read or written.” Still, Mac file “permissions” don’t appear to be the issue.
- The following converters were tried, but each failed: Any Video Converter, iSquint, HitPaw, Movavi, MPEG StreamClip, Prism, VideoProc, VLC, Wondershare UniConverter, and several free online converters.

Comment: Do you know which application was used back then to create the disk?

Comment: Moving this to SuperUser.

Comment: The videos were originally produced with the now-defunct Studio 8 program for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I infer from the copy error that your disc(s) are scratched. In this case you may have to use a data recovery tool instead.

But if you are assured it is not so and the problem lies with the tools you are using try:

`ffmpeg -i <input_filename.dat> <output_filename.mp4>`

If you are comfortable with the commandline. Of course you would have to install FFmpeg (https://ffmpeg.org/) first. Never failed me.

Or try HandBrake (https://handbrake.fr/) if you really need a GUI.

If the scratches are really bad you may never be able to recover it.

Comment: On a 20-year-old disk it may not even be scratches, the substrate itself could be failing, or the drive's lens being misted with time. I had a similar issue recently, eventually solved by going round the building trying every machine with an optical drive until I found one that could read better than the others.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response, GJ. The disks themselves, other than being 20 years old, are flawless. They were slipped into jewel boxes immediately after copying and placed in cool, dark, dry storage. I'll follow your ffmpeg and handbrake suggestions and see what happens.

Comment: Handbrake gave me a “No Valid Source Found” error message. I'm suspecting these videos are moving slide presentations. My family never had photos, per se, just Kodak slides, which I think at some point my father digitized and slid into these video files.

Comment: @MEsk, There are certain hacks which could produce discs with wonderful results based on the device which plays them. I don't know if they work equally well inside Apple environments. Could you try copying them to a Windows or Linux based machine?

Comment: If nothing else works you could also try playing them on a software and capturing the render.

Comment: Looking into the history of compact disc digital videos (VCDs), I ran into Canadian Mireth Technology (mireth.com) where I found a VCD knowledge bank as well as Mac VCD software (MacVDC X)that smoothly opened and played my problem CDs! (VCDs are now dated video tech that DVDs eclipsed decades ago.) That's one victory. Now we'll see if conversion to a more broadly playable format is possible. As you say, if nothing else I can find a way to record what this player software provides. Many thanks for your input. I'll report back.

Comment: The VCD-playing software opens, plays, and converts my problem VCDs to MOV. Then, converting the MOVs to MP4s is a no brainer! One simply has to recognize a VCD for what it is and then apply the proper tool, but--as is often the case with antiques--you may not readily recognize what you have.